# Symfony 2 Entity field type with doctrine querybuilder and leftjoin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need some help with the Symfony 2 entity type field. I have a indexAction function with a form builder:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($add)
    ->add('model', 'text')
    ->add('adType', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'FrontendAdBundle:AdType',
        'property' => 'name', // ? adTypeTransl.name needed
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            global $request;
            $result = $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.adTypeTransl', 'tr')
            ->where('tr.lang = hr');

            return $result;
        },
    ));
```

I have two db tables named "AdType" & "AdTypeTransl".

AdType:
id, system_name

```
1 | sell
2 | rent
```

AdTypeTransl:
id, lang, ad_type, name

```
1 | hr | 1 | Prodaja
2 | hr | 2 | Najam
```

As you can see i would like to leftjoin adTypeTransl to adType and display a select list with id values of Adtype and Text of AdTypeTransl.

I generate entities with YML. Here is what I have for now.

```
AdType
    oneToMany:
        adTypes:
            targetEntity: AdTypeTransl
            mappedBy: adTypeCat
```

and

```
AdTypeTransl
    manyToOne:
        adTypeCat:
            targetEntity: AdType
            inversedBy: adTypes
            joinColumn:
                name: ad_type
                referencedColumnName: id
```

I can only get one table values at the time in my select list like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="adType.id">adType.system_name</option>
</select>
```

But what I really need is:

```
<select>
    <option value="adType.id">adTypeTransl.name</option>
</select>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using symfony's translator to translate these values? You could register your translations from `AdTypeTransl` (strange name btw) with the translator and you'd be done.

Comment: Yes, these types will be added later on dynamically from a web interface.